Conflicting peer dependency (react/NextJS 15.0)
While working on a web app with NextJS 15.0, I am hitting some issues. Here is a log I get after running firebase deploy:
2024-10-23T02_18_48_690Z-eresolve-report.txt
'Log files:
/Users/me/.npm/_logs/2024-10-23T02_18_48_690Z-debug-0.log

# npm resolution error report

While resolving: @react-google-maps/api@2.20.3
Found: react@19.0.0-rc-65a56d0e-20241020
node_modules/react
  react@"19.0.0-rc-65a56d0e-20241020" from the root project
  peer react@"^18.2.0 || 19.0.0-rc-65a56d0e-20241020" from next@15.0.0
  node_modules/next
    next@"15.0.0" from the root project
  peer react@"19.0.0-rc-65a56d0e-20241020" from react-dom@19.0.0-rc-65a56d0e-20241020
  node_modules/react-dom
    react-dom@"19.0.0-rc-65a56d0e-20241020" from the root project
    peer react-dom@"^18.2.0 || 19.0.0-rc-65a56d0e-20241020" from next@15.0.0
    node_modules/next
      next@"15.0.0" from the root project
  peer react@">= 16.8.0 || 17.x.x || ^18.0.0-0 || ^19.0.0-0" from styled-jsx@5.1.6
  node_modules/styled-jsx
    styled-jsx@"5.1.6" from next@15.0.0
    node_modules/next
      next@"15.0.0" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"^16.8 || ^17 || ^18" from @react-google-maps/api@2.20.3
node_modules/@react-google-maps/api
  @react-google-maps/api@"^2.20.3" from the root project

Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.3.1
node_modules/react
  peer react@"^16.8 || ^17 || ^18" from @react-google-maps/api@2.20.3
  node_modules/@react-google-maps/api
    @react-google-maps/api@"^2.20.3" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

That seems to have to do with some react version conflicts, but I do not see exactly what to do. One first question coming to mind is:
What is meant by "this command" at the end of the report that I should try to run with the --legacy-peer-deps option ?
The problems start when running this command:
me@MyMac myapp % npm i firebase react-firebase-hooks react-router-dom react-tabs @react-google-maps/api                   
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: myapp@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@19.0.0-rc-69d4b800-20241021
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"19.0.0-rc-69d4b800-20241021" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8 || ^17 || ^18" from @react-google-maps/api@2.20.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-google-maps/api
npm ERR!   @react-google-maps/api@"^2.20.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2024-10-26T08_30_13_988Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2024-10-26T08_30_13_988Z-debug-0.log
me@MyMac myapp % 

But using the --legacy-peer-deps option does not solve the problem either:
me@MyMac myapp % npm i firebase react-firebase-hooks react-router-dom react-tabs @react-google-maps/api --legacy-peer-deps
npm WARN deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm WARN deprecated @humanwhocodes/config-array@0.13.0: Use @eslint/config-array instead
npm WARN deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead
npm WARN deprecated eslint@8.57.1: This version is no longer supported. Please see https://eslint.org/version-support for other options.

added 463 packages, and audited 464 packages in 8s

138 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
me@MyMac myapp % 

It only looks better but the same problems come back again when running firebase deploy.
..... I have tried further experiments ...
When running the npx command these lines are automatically added to package.json:
"dependencies": {
  "react": "19.0.0-rc-69d4b800-20241021",
  "react-dom": "19.0.0-rc-69d4b800-20241021",
  "next": "15.0.1"
},

Then when doing: npm i firebase; the line below is added to the dependencies (above):
"firebase": "^11.0.1",

To avoid known problems, I replace the react lines in the dependencies section by:
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "18.2.0",

Then when running: firebase deploy, we hit the issue hereafter.
Building a Cloud Function to run this application. This is needed due to:
 • non-static component /GPSFix/[rcdId]/page

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: firebase-frameworks@0.11.4
npm ERR! Found: firebase@11.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/firebase
npm ERR!   firebase@"^11.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer firebase@">= 9.0.0" from react-firebase-hooks@5.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-firebase-hooks
npm ERR!     react-firebase-hooks@"^5.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional firebase@"^9.9.0 || ^10.0.0" from firebase-frameworks@0.11.4
npm ERR! node_modules/firebase-frameworks
npm ERR!   firebase-frameworks@"^0.11.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: firebase@10.14.1
npm ERR! node_modules/firebase
npm ERR!   peerOptional firebase@"^9.9.0 || ^10.0.0" from firebase-frameworks@0.11.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/firebase-frameworks
npm ERR!     firebase-frameworks@"^0.11.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2024-10-28T05_48_20_413Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2024-10-28T05_48_20_413Z-debug-0.log

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.


Next wants either react 18 or 19 and seems to use 19, while the google-maps-api is not supporting 19. Have you tried setting react to version 18 manually in your package.json? What version of react is defined in your package.json?

@Tim. I see. Following your hint I have tried a bit further. But there are still problems down the road. Please have a look at my updated post. It also answers your question about package.json.

Have you added firebase-frameworks manually to your package.json-file? I found the package on npm, but it has no documentation and does not support firebase 11. Seems like there is a version mismatch between firebase and firebase-frameworks.

I use the packages firebase and react-firebase-hooks. The first one install without any issue that I can see, the second one shows conflicts. I don't remember that I have ever used firebase-frameworks.
