Route "/[locale]" used `params.locale`. `params` should be awaited before using its properties
I'm working on a Next.js 15 app using the new App Router (app directory) with dynamic route localization. I have a [locale] directory where I handle multiple language routes, and I use the params object to access the locale value. However, I keep getting the following error when trying to access params.locale:
Error: Route "/[locale]" used `params.locale`. `params` should be awaited before using its properties. Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sync-dynamic-apis
    at locale (webpack:///app/[locale]/layout.tsx?a262:30:34)

Code Structure
Here's the structure of my app:
app/
├── [locale]/
│   ├── layout.tsx            // Root layout for [locale] dynamic route
│   └── page.tsx              // Main page component for [locale] dynamic route
locales/
├── en/
│   └── common.json           // English translations
├── lt/
│   └── common.json           // Lithuanian translations
i18Config.js                  // i18n configuration with available locales
i18n.js                       // i18n initialization file
TranslationsProvider.js       // Translation provider component
middleware.js                 // Middleware to handle locale-based redirection


In app/[locale]/layout.tsx, I want to access the locale value from params and pass it to different components. I have tried various ways to access params, but the error persists.
Here's what my layout.tsx file looks like:
import "@/styles/global.css";
import { Outfit } from "next/font/google";
import { Providers } from "./providers";
import i18nConfig from "../../i18nConfig";
import { dir } from "i18next";

const outfit = Outfit({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  weight: ["300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800"],
  style: ["normal"],
});

export function generateStaticParams() {
  return i18nConfig.locales.map((locale) => ({ locale }));
}

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
  params: { locale },
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: { locale: string };
}) {
  return (
    <html
      lang={locale}
      dir={dir(locale)}
      suppressHydrationWarning
      className={outfit.className}
    >
      <body className="bg-background">
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}



Accessing params directly in the function body: I've moved params.locale to a separate constant in the function body, but the error still appears.
Using generateStaticParams: I added generateStaticParams to pre-generate routes for the available locales (en and lt). This didn't resolve the error either.
Type Adjustments: I created a custom type for params to ensure TypeScript knows the structure of params (i.e., params: { locale: string }).

The error suggests that params should be "awaited," even though params is an object and not a promise, so await params doesn’t make sense here.
I’ve seen other posts mentioning that destructuring in async functions can cause issues with params in Next.js, but accessing params directly also didn’t work for me.
Restarting the server after every change didn’t resolve the issue either.
How can I correctly access params.locale in a dynamic route layout without getting this error? Is there a workaround or configuration I’m missing? Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79113322/nextjs-react-type-does-not-satisfy-constraint/79113867#79113867

I just found the problem (and it makes no sense at all).
This is the layout.tsx code and it seems to be correct:
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
  params,
}: RootLayoutProps) {
  const { lang } = await params

  return (
    <html lang={lang}>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}

In my case, the icon.png file was triggering the warning.
With warning:
/src
  /app
    /[lang]
      /layout.tsx
      /icon.png

Without warning:
/src
  /app
    /icon.png
    /[lang]
      /layout.tsx

That's it:

/app/[lang]/icon.png - Warning
/app/icon.png - No warning


I think when you place icon.png inside [lang] it treats it as a route specific asset or maybe Next.js expects files like pages or components inside route directory that's why it triggers warning and works well when icon.png place outside which then available globally.

As of Next.js version 15 you must await the params to resolve this. Here is an example:
export default async function RootLayout({children, params }: { children: React.ReactNode; params: Promise<{ locale: string }> }) {
  const { locale } = await params;
  return()
}

let me know if it works for you.

It does not working... I think that this 'use' function can not be use in the Server side component, because I get different erros with your solution. Client component can use this your solution and it works fine, but on Server side component it does not working...  In server component i use this const { locale } = await params; and it works fine for my.  But it is very strange think why this 'params' is Promise? I can not understand that...

In latest Next js version 15 they have changed the way we use params in older versions and made them promise instead and you are right in SSR you have to use async await because "use" is a hook and cant be used in SSR and only be used in CSR.

The official Next.js 15 documentation (https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sync-dynamic-apis#possible-ways-to-fix-it) suggests this exact solution. But it doesn't work.
I tried running the auto-fix script, and all it did was to add the async/await. Also didn't work.
The warning still shows up. Maybe it's a v15 bug

You should await params, like:
export async function POST(request: Request, { params }: { params: Promise<{ unit_id: string }> }) {

and then:
const { unit_id: unitId } = await params

for example.



export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
  params,
}: RootLayoutProps) {
  const locale = (await params).locale

  return (
    <html lang={lang}>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}




For reference, what you need to await is the params because, as Next15 Dynamic APIs are Asynchronous Official Docs
For example, you have a Page Component getting the id from the params like
export default async function Page(props: { params: { id: string } }) 

Then it would have to change to a Promise type like this:
export default async function Page(props: { params: Promise<{ id: string }> }) 

And access through the await of params like this:
const { id } = await props.params;

