How to implement dynamic routing using a JSON file in Nextjs
I have a small web application that fetches data from a JSON file. I want to display this data using dynamic routes. Here's the code I've been trying.
import React from "react";
import data from "@/app/courses.json";

export default function Page({ params }) {
  const { id } = params;
  const course = data.find((item) => item.id === id);
  console.log(id);

  if (!course) {
    return (
      <div className="mt-96">
        <h2>Curso no encontrado</h2>
        <p>Por favor, verifica el ID del curso.</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  const { name, description } = course;

  return (
    <div className="mt-96">
      <h2>{name}</h2>
      <p>{description}</p>
    </div>
  );
}


I've tested a few things but they haven't worked as the value always returns undefined."
I'm trying to use dynamic routes with a local JSON file.

Which version of next.js are you using? if it is v15, you need to await for params. See link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79113322/nextjs-react-type-does-not-satisfy-constraint/79113867?noredirect=1#comment139505479_79113867
